# How to get trackpad working on Surface Pro 3 with 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, surface

I've just upgraded my dual booted Surface Pro 3 from Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04 via 15.10. It mostly seems to be working however the Trackpad on the type cover isn't. Any ideas how to get it to work?

The left and right click and keyboard are working. The model number of the Trackpad is 1644.

I'm a total newbie to Ubuntu & Linux and have no idea how to go about working this kind of thing out.

Comment: You could try this solution, which apparently worked for Ubuntu 15.10: http://www.intothewebs.com/surface-pro-3-fix-trackpad-in-linux/

Comment: This guide and accompanying discussion might also be useful, the author says the trackpad works: https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/4l8iv1/surface_book_1604_install_step_by_step/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A snippet from [Nick Weinberg's link](https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/4l8iv1/surface_book_1604_install_step_by_step/) seems to have done the trick.

Entering this into terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tigerite/kernel/ubuntu trusty main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tigerite-kernel-trusty.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 984AE706D31B333A && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-surface
```